# Прочитать информацию из файла в несколько масивов

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Есть файл. в него записал фамилии и оценки из соответствующих массивов. В файле строки имеют вид: (Фамилия ; оценка) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь прочитать информацию в другие два массива?

```
package com.company;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Class_File {
    public void writeFile() {
        String temp;
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Main.name.length; i++) {
            temp = Main.name[i] + " ; " + Main.score[i];
            pw.println(temp);
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: в какие другие два? Что должно получиться в итоге?

Comment: Изначально есть два массива - типов String и double. Я их содержимое записал в файл. А тепрь нужно записать информацию из файла в два других массива таких же типов.

Comment: Что, никто не знает, как запилить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void readFile() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr))
    {
        String temp;
        int index = 0;
        while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] parts = temp.split(";");
            Main.name[index] = parts[0];
            Main.score[index] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Читай построчно каждую строку, дели по символу `;`, в один массив добавляй первый элемент, в другой - второй.

Comment: А как в массивы добавлять?  void readFile() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String temp = "";
        while(temp != null) {
            temp = reader.readLine();
            temp.split(";");
        }

    }